# How to fetch authenticated username in web api (token based authentication)

Tags: angularjs, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, token

I have implemented token based web api authentication.

Now, on web api side, I need to fetch authenticated username but its unable to fetch.

when i try to access using `RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name` then it shows `null` value.

In worst case, I need to pass username from angualrjs on each request. It would be really best if it retrieve from web api itself.

can any one please help, how can i fetch authenticated user from web api side.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set username to claim.

```
 var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("sub");
    string username = claim.Value
```